# Error while compiling flutter app for android with firebase_remote_config

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I have a flutter app with firebase_remote_config library as one of the dependencies.  IOS compiles fine, android throws the following error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:preReleaseBuild'.
>   Android dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common' has different version for the compile (16.0.3) and runtime (16.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

Now, I know how to fix it, but I would like to understand how these versions get mixed up.  The fix is to downgrade

> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.1.0'

to

> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3'

in

> plugins/firebase_remote_config/android/build.gradle

But where is this **16.0.3** version coming from?  File search returns nothing...